# A problems with handling matrix by several of threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I'm trying to change the main diagonal of the matrix by multithreading.
Each thread has a unique number: 21, 17, 16, 26, 7.
But the problem is only one (common first) thread works and changes only first element of the matrix.
Multithreading is new to me. So I don't know what should I do.

This is from class which extends Thread

```
@Override
   public void run() {

       int[][] m = matrix.getMatrix();
       for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
               if ((i == j && m[i][j] == 0) && locker.tryLock()){
                   locker.lock();
                   matrix.setElement(number, i, j);
                   try {
                       TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                   }catch (InterruptedException e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }finally {
                       locker.unlock(); 
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

This is from class Matrix

```
public void setElement(int element, int i, int j){
    matrix[i][j] = element;
}
```

This is from Main class

```
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new NumberSetter(matrix, locker, numbers[i]));
        threads[i] = thread;
        thread.start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By first look you are locking twice - once with locker.tryLock() and once more with locker.lock(). Remove the latter as it's not needed.
Also the "m[i][j] == 0" check should be inside locked code.